# Can't extend enum; what should I use instead?

Tags: swift

I'm doing some tests with classes and super-classes. Most of it makes sense, but there's one thing (at the moment!) that I'm unsure of. I'm using an enum in my superclass, and I'd like to expand it in my class. I'm pretty sure I can't do that, but I'm not sure what to do instead - suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as would any pointers to a really good, detailed link on classes.

Here's roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
class basicSprite: SKSpriteNode {
// This is the super-class
  enum state: Int {
    Paused, Idle, Damaged, Dead
  }
  var currentState = state.Paused
  ....
}

class playerSprite: basicSprite {
  extend enum state: Int {
    // This should take the enum state from the super-class and
    // add these 4 states, giving 8 in total
    case MovingLeft, MovingRight, MovingUp, MovingDown
  }
  ....
}

var newPlayer: playerSprite
newPlayer.state = MovingLeft
....
switch newPlayer.state {
  case playerSprite.state.Idle: break
  case playerSprite.state.MovingLeft: break
  default: break
}
```

Now as far as I can tell, I can't do that with an enum - what should I use instead? Or if I can do that with an enum, how?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I would use string values to represent the state e.g. case "Idle":

Comment: why don't you add a new class with readonly instances and a protected constructor?

Comment: @DanielA.White - I don't follow. If you could show me an example it'd be a big help!

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit publicly, you get the variable into  the base class.

so, directly add the other values into your previous enum

Comment: I thought about that, but I plan to create another class based off basicSprite, which should only inherit the original 4 states, not the 4 from playerSprite. I can find other ways around it, just thought this was an elegant solution and wanted to know how I could do it!